# Display Keyboard for EditText in Emulator (GenyMotion) Android 4.3

Tags: android, android-edittext, emulation, android-softkeyboard, genymotion

Does anybody know how to display the keyboard in the emulator when the EditText field has focus. I have tried so many solutions but none of them work. I am working in android 4.3 Jelly Bean. The Emulator I am using is GenyMotion. I would also like to know how to hide the keyboard when the EditText field loses focus. I assume however if the keyboard does not appear in the emulator it won't appear when testing on the device.

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 42):

Just check the details of your emulator. Soft Keyboard won't be displayed if you have checked the option "Hardware Keyboard Present", uncheck that option. And it will automatically displayed on the device since device doesn't have hard keyboard.

Comment: Hi Rajat. Yes thats correct I am using GenyMotion emulator and under the configuration option I had to check the use virtual keyboard for typing. So now when my EditText get focus the virtual(soft) Keyboard is displayed perfect thanks.

Answer (score 12):

`Close emulator` -> `Setting button` -> `Check Use virtual keyboard for text input`

[image]

Answer (score 8):

run Genymotion as the application from windows or mac (not from android studio plugin)

then select the settings sign on the right of the virtual device you have installed from the virtualdevicelist

choose the 'use virtual keyboard for textinput'
then close the application.

this worked for me in genymotion 2.6.0

Answer (score 5):

Try this it work for me:

GO to settings menu ->Language&Input->turn off the Hardware Physical keyboard.

Answer (score 3):

First of All close Genymotion emulator.
Then Start Genymotion Application
From left side menu open   `Filters -> Source -> Genymotion` Now check the checkBox of Genymotion if already unchecked.[image]

Then from installed devices select `three doted icon -> Edit` Then in edit window go down in `Android System Option` And check the checkBox of `Use virtual keyboard for text input`[image]

Answer (score 0):

For new versions of Genymotion (mine is 3.1.0),

- Right click on your virtual device and click **"edit"**
- Then choose **"Use virtual keyboard for text input"** and click **"CONFIRM"**