# keyboard isn't showing up when edit text is touched

Tags: android, android-studio, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I am testing my app on genymotion. I want the keyboard to show up when an edit text is touched please help me with this. [this is the screen shot of my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3izu.png)

Here is the xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="#5a5ab5"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"

android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:clickable="false">

<com.github.florent37.materialtextfield.MaterialTextField
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/view"
    app:mtf_image="@drawable/phon"
    android:id="@+id/view3">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/phoneNo"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:background="@drawable/phone"
    android:hint="Phone Number"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Comment: when you open a virtual device there is one setting option. go to setting and check "Use virtual keyboard for text input". and then start your genymotion device.

Comment: I have checked that in too that's why i am so much wondering why is my every method failing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you described on code you used [Material Library](https://github.com/florent37/MaterialTextField) in your code. please read this library documentation.
To Show Keyboard code is already described in description.

```
app:mtf_openKeyboardOnFocus="true"
```

add in your material views, [Material Library Description](https://github.com/florent37/MaterialTextField#available-attributes) here.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the below code in your Manifest file (inside your activity tag):

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"
```

OR

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just checked the library you are using, found out there are few attributes that could be used:
    app:mtf_cardCollapsedHeight="4dp"
    app:mtf_image="@drawable/ic_mail_grey600_24dp"
    app:mtf_animationDuration="1000"
    app:mtf_labelColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    app:mtf_openKeyboardOnFocus="true">

Did you tried using these?

It has this attribute "app:mtf_openKeyboardOnFocus", could do the trick.

Comment: Thank you Mukesh Sharma i just forgot to use those attributes now it's working like a charm thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this way it will show the Keyboard when the `EditText` is focus

```
EditText phoneNo= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phoneNo);
phoneNo.requestFocus();
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

Comment: I have tried this method so many times and now too but it isn't working :(

Comment: @HumanOidRoBo I update my answer try with this just copy and paste it.

Answer (score 0):

In Your Layout xml file Add this Line in To EditText

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

this will work for me.

refer this link
[Display Keyboard for EditText in Emulator (GenyMotion) Android 4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26605228/display-keyboard-for-edittext-in-emulator-genymotion-android-4-3)

Comment: I tried it now still the keyboard isn't showing up in my genymotion emulator.

Comment: Please check "Use virtual keyboard for text input" is checked or not in your genymotion device.

Answer (score 0):

you can onClick Edittextbox using this method.

```
private void showKeyBoard(){
            ((InputMethodManager)Context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).showSoftInputFromInputMethod(editTextBox_name.getWindowToken(),0);

}
```

Comment: What is mContext and search_name? it is giving me error

Comment: mContext is Context content and search_name is EditTextBox name let you change.